# What's the difference of numpy.ndarray.T and numpy.ndarray.transpose() when self.ndim < 2

Tags: python, numpy

The document [numpy.ndarray.T](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy-ndarray-t) says

> ndarray.T — Same as self.transpose(), except that self is returned if self.ndim < 2.

Also, ndarray.transpose(*axes) says

> For a 1-D array, this has no effect.

Doesn't this mean the same thing?

Here's a little demo snippet:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.__version__
1.5.1rc1
>>> a = np.arange(7)
>>> print a, a.T, a.transpose()
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: There's no effective difference (they both return views into the original array).  In fact, the documentation appears (?) to be wrong about `ndarray.T`... `self` does not seem to be returned. In other words, `x is not x.T`, even when it's a 1D array. (The contents are identical, but it returns a new object with a view into the same contents each time).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Regardless of rank, the `.T` attribute and the `.transpose()` method are the same—they both return the transpose of the array.

In the case of a rank 1 array, the `.T` and `.transpose()` don't do anything—they both return the array.

Comment: I guess what is meant is that `.T` and the `transpose()` _call_ both return the transpose of the array. In fact, `.T` return the transpose of the array, while `transpose` is a _more general_ method_ that can be given axes (`transpose(*axes)`, with defaults that make the call `transpose()` equivalent to `.T`).

Answer (score 9):

It looks like `.T` is just a convenient notation, and that `.transpose(*axes)` is the more general function and is intended to give more flexibility, as axes can be specified.  They are apparently not implemented in Python, so one would have to look into C code to check this.