# T in multivariate distribution in python

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I saw a code for generating numbers from multivariate distribution but could not understand what is ".T" here used for? I could not find it elsewhere I searched for.

```
  x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000).T
```

Comment: Try searching for `numpy t`. The "numpy" part is important context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here .T in numpy stands is for Transpose

Comment: Can we use numpy.transpose() here?

Comment: Yes, you can use transpose() here as it is effectively the same as T. In fact, .T is a convenient form of transpose(). For more detailed answer refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068177/whats-the-difference-of-numpy-ndarray-t-and-numpy-ndarray-transpose-when-self)